# cabeçalho, menu lateral e rodapé em todas as páginas

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Como utilizar o mesmo rodapé, menu lateral e cabeçalho em todas as páginas do meu site? Para o header e footer, tentei o seguinte:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");
        });
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>

    <h1>conteúdo</h1>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

mas não vai; apenas o conteúdo aparece. Os arquivos header/footer.html e jquery estão na mesma pasta, todos com nomes e extensões corretas. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Vc está fazendo isso em servidor ou na máquina local?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo É que o método não funciona no Chrome via protocolo FILE. No Firefox, por exemplo, funciona.

Comment: realmente, testei aqui no Mozilla e deu certo. Obrigada!!!
mas como fazer pra ele funcionar no Chrome também?

Comment: @dvd, tonces é local

Comment: O  problema é que o .load () para arquivos locais é bloqueado pelo Chrome por motivos de segurança. Parece que há uma solução em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592926/jquery-load-method-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/